# swift :how to change the brightness and contrast of a usb webcam

Tags: usb, avfoundation, webcam, brightness, pan

How to control the brightness, contrast, pan and tilt of a USB webcam (the device supports all these feature). With AVFoundation we can preview and record from the webcam, but not able to change brightness , contrast , pan , tilt like operations programatically.
Is there any other way to control these properties of recording devices ?
Thanks in advance.